# Jenkins: Copy from build folder on master to workspace on slave

Tags: jenkins, build

I have installed Test Complete plugin on my Jenkins instance and I would like to copy the junitResult.xml that is generated in the build folder on the master to the workspace on the slave. Is it possible to do this securly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone is interested by this topic, 
I have sucessfully done it by using a groovy script. In my case (TestComplete plugin integration with Jenkins), I copied a file named junitResult.xml to the workspace. Here is the scipt:

```
import hudson.FilePath;
import hudson.Launcher;
import hudson.model.AbstractBuild;
import hudson.model.BuildListener;

FilePath getMasterLogDirectory(AbstractBuild build) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String buildDir = build.getRootDir().getAbsolutePath();
  FilePath masterLogDirectory = new FilePath(new File(buildDir + File.separator + "junitResult.xml"));
  return masterLogDirectory;
}

FilePath getSlaveWorkspace(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String workspacePath = build.getEnvironment(listener).get("WORKSPACE");
    if (workspacePath == null) {
      throw new IOException(Messages.TcTestBuilder_InternalError());
    }

  FilePath projectWorkspaceOnSlave = new FilePath(launcher.getChannel(), workspacePath);
  projectWorkspaceOnSlave.mkdirs();
  return projectWorkspaceOnSlave.absolutize();
}

def junitName = "junitResult.xml"

FilePath slaveWorkspacePath = getSlaveWorkspace(build, launcher, listener)

FilePath  slaveJunitFilePath = new FilePath(slaveWorkspacePath, junitName);

getMasterLogDirectory(build).copyTo(slaveJunitFilePath )
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use the pipeline, then you can use stash/ustash option.

Stash the junitResult.xml file on master node, and then unstash on another node to workspace.

Comment: This would be a good solution but TestComplete jenkins plugin is not compatible with the pipeline.

Comment: `stash` is for files in the build's _workspace_ directory. The question is about files in the _build record_ folder, which is not the same. `stash` cannot work.

Answer (score -1):

1) install "Copy Artifact Plugin"
2) master job post build step: archive the artifacts **junitResult.xml**
3) slave job build step: Copy artifacts from other projects - specify project name, which build and artifact to copy - **junitResult.xml**

Comment: This solution is not compliant with what I want to do because to archive an artifact, it should be in the workspace but mine is in the build folder.

Comment: add shell step: cd $your_build_folder && cp junitResult.xml $WORKSPACE,
and then archive the artifact

Comment: This is my problem: the build folder is in the master machine (host of jenkins instance) and the job run on a node. They are on separated machines and I am searching for a secure way to copy the file.

Comment: so, to clearify, your MASTER runs job on a node. Is this node a slave? If no, how does it run? ssh on remote host?

Comment: Yes the node is a slave. I have the master (0 executor) and a slave where I execute the job (1 executor).

Comment: so, you build smth locally, on master( not using jenkins). And junitresult is generated. After that you want it to be copied on slave node, correct?

Comment: Here is what I do: I have created a job, that job will run on a specific slave and will call Test Complete plugin. This plugin is writting in build folder and not in workspace. The build folder is not on the slave but on the master. I want to copy the files in the build folder to the workspace, so from the master to the slave.

Comment: >  job will run on a specific *slave* and will call Test Complete plugin.
So, how is it possible  "This plugin is writting in build folder and not in workspace and build folder is not on *slave*"

Comment: When a job run, it write in the build folder on the master even if the job run on a slave. You can, for example, find the logs of the build in this folder.

Comment: bad practise.. running build on slave that leaves file on master, and then willing to get this file back to slave? why do you even use slave build folder? it is what they are made for.

Comment: This is how the plugin works, if I was the developer of the plugin I would not have done it like this. But to do what I want to do I need this file so this is why I'm searching for a solution.

Comment: just find a workaround, for example use scp in a shell step to copy that xml from master builddir back to slave. Assuming you're working with linux

Comment: How can I do if I haven't access to the machine (I don't have the credentials to connect to it)?

Comment: You didn't even say about that. You have no credentials to connect you master from slave, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm searching if we can do this with a Groovy script but for now I haven't found the solution yet.